# general sql error

Tags: postgresql

I have  created an  application in  delphi and  backend  is postgres  when i run the application  i get the  following error

```
general sql error.could not connect to the server;no  
connection could be  made  because the  target machine actively refused 
it.[127.0.0.1:1:5433 alias resumep
```

I  uninstalled  it and installed  it again but it didnt work.Even i changed the port number while installing .
I changed the password and installed again but its giving same error
what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database cluster of a **standard PostgreSQL installation** is listening on port **5432**. (You can, of course, set up additional db clusters on different ports or configure your database cluster to listen on any other port.)

Any particular reason you try **5433**? This is probably the cause of your problem.
If no server is listening on port 5433, the connection is simply not possible.